# Is there a Java Library for validation of SI measurements and specific medical measurements?

Tags: java, regex

I’m looking for a way to validate if certain literals are a valid expression for SI measurements, e.g., "2kg", or specific medical measurements, e.g., "120mmHg", "3mmol/l" or "IIa".

I thought about using regex with Pattern and Matcher in Java.

Simple(!) example for "kg":

```
String literal = "2kg";
String kilogramRegEx = "[0-9]+kg";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(kilogramRegEx);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(literal);
matcher.matches();
```

Is there are better and more elegant way to achieve something like that?

Preferably I would use an existing and accepted Java Library like Apache Commons or something similar. However, I haven’t stumbled across one.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but a Google search for "java units library" shows a few dead projects, but some reasonable areas that you can investigate, including http://unitsofmeasurement.github.io/ https://github.com/gnapse/metric and http://units-in-java.sourceforge.net/  I haven't used any of these, and they are primarily focused on unit conversion rather than simple unit parsing, but look like they will solve your problem.

Comment: you might also take a look at this [github project file](https://github.com/nasa/trick/blob/master/trick_source/java/src/trick/common/utils/UnitType.java)